# Insert NSStrings into NSStrings

Tags: nsstring, viewcontroller, iboutlet

I'm new to Objective C and have a pretty basic question. So I have 2 variables (IBOutlets that are UITextFields) in one UIViewController. After the user enters text into those UITextFields, s/he proceeds to a new viewcontroller. When the user enters viewcontroller #2, I want to insert the values of the IBOutlets from viewcontroller #1 into an NSString I preset. For example, 1 variable is a name and one is an interest. The NSString should read "Hello [name], thanks for your interest in [interest]. We appreciate it." So how do I pass the IBOutlets from viewcontroller 1 to viewcontroller 2, and insert them as NSStrings into the NSString that isn't variable (the thanks for your interest, etc. etc. part). I appreciate any help you can provide because I'm a total Objective C newbie. Thanks for taking the time to read this.

-Reynold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a two part question. To put those strings together the way you want to, I'd recommend:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:FORMAT];
```

In your case, the implementation would probably be a little like this:

```
NSString *name = nameTextField.text;
NSString *interest = interestTextField.text;

NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@, thanks for your interest in %@. We appreciate it",
                                                                  name, 
                                                              interest];
```

Passing this value to another view controller is a little bit more complicated. I recommend creating a property in the second view controller like so:

```
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController{
    NSString *myString;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;

@end
```

Then, when you set up the new view controller you can configure it like this:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];

vc.myString = resultString;

[self.view addSubview:vc.view];
[vc release];
```

Good luck.

Comment: God dammit, beat me to it. ;)

Comment: It was a good race @esqew. Everyone who's been working in Cocoa for more than a month was probably furiously typing that one out...

Comment: Thanks, Aurum! Wasn't expecting such a prompt response :) And thanks esqew for trying :)